# What's a good alternative to setting XCUIDevice.shared.orientation for changing the orientation during XCTests in Xcode 13?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios15, xcode13

What's a good alternative to setting XCUIDevice.shared.orientation for changing the orientation during XCTests in Xcode 13?

Many of our app's existing snapshot tests set the device orientation using:

```
XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = orientation.deviceOrientation
```

However in Xcode 13, these tests fail due to the following exception being thrown when this method is called:

> **Failed to set device orientation: Not authorized for performing UI testing actions.**
> Exception _XCTestCaseInterruptionException * 0x60000082b060 0x000060000082b060

Googling this error led me to find [this Flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84162) where they state:

> I guess Xcode 13 will limit the use of XCUIDevice to XCUITests.

Our snapshot tests are not XCUITests, though, so what options do we have to force a particular device rotation so that we can snapshot the way the view would look in landscape and portrait?

Comment: Sorry but this makes no sense. How can your tests that take snapshots not be UI tests? Is it because of something about Flutter? (Sorry, I know nothing about Flutter.)

Comment: We don't use Flutter. I only mention Flutter because it came up in Google when I searched for "XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = orientation.deviceOrientation". Our tests that take snapshots are not XCUITests, they are just XCTests with a host application using FBSnapshotTestCase framework. XCUITests don't let you `@testable import` anything from the app, so it's not useful for snapshot tests where we need to configure certain classes with mock models etc.

Comment: Well, that is not true. I mean yes, it's true that you can't do a testable import; you can't see into the code from a UI test. But a UI test can inject environment variables into the app, where the app itself can configure itself in a special way for testing. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199055/xcode-ui-test-environment-variables-not-being-passed-from-scheme on how to do that. Basically I would take issue with the entire premise of your question; you should be doing UI testing for snapshots. — I've given that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976545/12587089) from @Dmytro on another question works for me, use:

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(
    NSNumber(integerLiteral: orientation.deviceOrientation.rawValue), 
    forKey: "orientation"
)
```

instead of:

```
XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = orientation.deviceOrientation
```

and now it works fine.

Note: `.deviceOrientation` refers to our custom extension on UIInterfaceOrientation:

```
public extension UIInterfaceOrientation {
    var deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation {
        switch self {
        case .landscapeLeft:
            return .landscapeRight
        case .landscapeRight:
            return .landscapeLeft
        case .portrait:
            return .portrait
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            return .portraitUpsideDown
        case .unknown:
            return .unknown
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take issue with the entire premise of your question; you should be doing UI testing for snapshots, not unit testing. UI testing has very powerful support for snapshotting as well as for dropping a lot of other information into the report for later retrieval.

It's true that a UI test can't reach into an app's code and make it behave. But to make the app behave in special ways during testing, a UI test can inject environment variables into the app, where the app itself can configure itself in a special way for testing. See for example [Xcode UI Test environment variables not being passed from Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199055/xcode-ui-test-environment-variables-not-being-passed-from-scheme) on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem in our project with snapshot tests. Unfortunately,
`UIDevice.current.setValue` didn't do the trick for us.

So, we decided to go with this solution:

1. add a new dummy UITest case file (not unit test case!):

[image]

2. name it starting with an 'A' so it would be the first in alphabetical order (and thus will be executed before other tests)
3. override `class setUp()` method with your code for changing device orientation. in our case it is changing it to portrait like so:

   ```
   override class func setUp() {
       super.setUp()
       if XCUIDevice.shared.orientation != .portrait {
           XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .portrait
       }
   }
   ```

3. add a dummy test, so setUp() will be executed:

   ```
   func testDummyTest() {
       XCTAssert(true)
   }
   ```

And that's it. Of course, it will not work when we trigger only one test and not a whole bundle, but as a workaround it can do. Hopefully, it will be fixed in future Xcode releases.

Here is the full code:

```
import XCTest

/// The class name should be the first in alphabetical order
class AUITestsSetUp: XCTestCase {

    override class func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        if XCUIDevice.shared.orientation != .portrait {
            XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .portrait
        }
    }

    func testDummyTest() {
        XCTAssert(true)
    }
}
```